# Reading Environment Variable values in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, environment-variables, performance-testing

I want to parametrize the testdata path, result path, server and port by defining them in environment variable.

I was able to achieve this to certain extent with `System.getenv("Jmeter_Result")` using it in *BeanShell processor*. But I need to use configuration element to fetch the value.

Can you kindly suggest.I am using Jmeter 3.1.

Answer (score 10):

According to https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do, `${__BeanShell( ... )}` may also help you on this issue.

For instance, one of our APIs needs OAuth2 authentication, and what I did was:

```
- Thread Group
    - User Defined Variables
        client_id     = ${__BeanShell( System.getenv("client_id") )}
        client_secret = ${__BeanShell( System.getenv("client_secret") )}
    - Once Only Controller
        - OAuth2 HTTP Request
    - API HTTP Request
```

Answer (score 6):

If the environment variable is made available via a System property then 
JMeter can access it using the `${__P("Jmeter_Result")}` function.

Otherwise, it's trivial to pass in the value of an environment variable using 
the -J option:

```
jmeter -JJmeter_Result=$Jmeter_Result
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I will go with _env() function. No need to update any files

Comment: I just want to clarify that works for me without double quotes `${__P(Jmeter_Result)}`

Answer (score 5):

There is [__env() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#envsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/), it seems to be something you're looking for.

You can install `__env()` and other [custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

[image: JMeter Plugins Custom Functions.]

Comment: Hi Dmitri, ${__env(Jmeter_Testdata,testdatapath,)}, but confused which configuration element to use. I want to fetch the values of Env Variable in the beginning. Can you kindly suggest. Thank you

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I used User defined variable to declare ${__env(Jmeter_Testdata,testdatapath,)} in the value section. Thanks a ton